# Sum of first N natural numbers in binary representation

Tags: java, c++

I need to find sum of first N natural numbers in binary form for example if N=3,
As 1 is represented in binary form as 01, 2 is represented in binary form as 10, 3 is represented in binary form as 11, required answer is 01 + 10 + 11 = 22 so the program should output 22.
My problem is the constraint for N is too high:
1<=N<=10^18
Any tips on approach to solve it?

Comment: The binary representation is a furfy.   The sum of the first N natural numbers is N*(N+1)/2 regardless of base (only the way it is output differs).   Work out a way to use a pair of unsigned 64-bit values to represent that result, and to print it out.

Comment: Hint: for N=7, the result is 444.

Comment: @Peter: The problem here (at least by the example in the question), is that the input is in binary base and the output is in decimal base. Obviously, the sum of 1, 2 and 3 is not 22, and 22 is not the sum of 1, 2 and 3 on any natural base (let alone, neither on binary base nor on decimal base).

Comment: I have updated the question with modified explanation

Comment: Your explanation doesn't work. 22 is not motivated by anything. You may want to copy the problem statement verbatim (to a new question, and please don't tag it with many programming language tags).

Comment: The problem statement is ambiguous. If N is large, the sum of lsb for example cannot be represented by a digit.

Comment: Are you sure you've understood the problem correctly? Summing the binary representation as decimal of all natural numbers from 1 to 10^18 is going to be an almighty number since there's like a quintillion terms. With N=10 you're already at 3455 (1+10+11+100+101+110+111+1000+1001+1010). Unless there's a trick to it you are expected to know it seems strange to me.